# Error Keepalived - FAULT state

Tags: shell, high-availability, keep-alive, failover

I'm trying to use keepalived to monitor some service. 
See my configuration file "keepalived.conf":

```
! Configuration File for keepalived
vrrp_script check_haproxy {
        script "/usr/local/bin/check_haproxy.sh"
        interval 2
        fail 2
        rise 2
}

vrrp_instance Vtest_2 {
        interface eno16777736

        track_interface {
                eno16777736
        }

        state BACKUP
        virtual_router_id 178
        priority 100
        nopreempt

        unicast_src_ip 172.28.7.132
        unicast_peer {
                172.28.7.133
        }

        virtual_ipaddress {
                195.221.2.14/32 dev eno16777736
        }

        track_script {
                check_haproxy
        }

        notify /usr/local/bin/keepalived.state.sh
}
```

In my script i to compare the number of the pid file and the process of the service :

```
#!/bin/bash
# check if haproxy is running, return 1 if not.
# Used by keepalived to initiate a failover in case haproxy is down

process=""
HAPROXY_STATUS=""

if [ -f "/var/run/haproxy.pid" ]
then
        process=$(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)
        HAPROXY_STATUS=$(ps -aux | grep -w "$process.*[h]aproxy")
fi

if [ "$HAPROXY_STATUS" ]
then
        exit 0
else
        exit 1
fi
```

My proble is that when i start keepalived when the command :

```
keepalived -f /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf --dont-fork --log-console --log-detail
```

Everythings works goods keepalived failover works good. But when i start the service with systemd:

```
systemctl start keepalived
```

I have this lines in my "/var/log/messages" file:

```
Mar 15 17:05:51 localhost systemd: Starting Session 10 of user root.
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost systemd: Starting LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor...
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived[34182]: Starting Keepalived v1.2.13 (11/20,2015)
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost systemd: Started LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor.
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived[34183]: Starting Healthcheck child process, pid=34184
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived[34183]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=34185
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Netlink reflector reports IP 172.28.7.132 added
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::20c:29ff:fe22:a18e added
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Configuration is using : 64365 Bytes
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: VRRP_Instance(Vtest_2) Entering BACKUP STATE
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(2), proto(112), unicast(1), fd(10,11)]
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[34184]: Netlink reflector reports IP 172.28.7.132 added
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[34184]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::20c:29ff:fe22:a18e added
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[34184]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[34184]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[34184]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[34184]: Configuration is using : 5344 Bytes
Mar 15 17:06:23 localhost Keepalived_healthcheckers[34184]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Mar 15 17:06:26 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[34185]: VRRP_Instance(Vtest_2) Now in FAULT state
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I have same problem when using address of my script in script section, but using commands is ok, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my `track_script` not running when starting keepalived as a systemctl service.

I found out that putting my `track_script` in `/usr/libexec/keepalived` solved the issue. It is probably related to [this issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1158115).

```
! Configuration File for keepalived

global_defs {
}

vrrp_script odr_check {
        script "/usr/libexec/keepalived/health_check.sh"
        interval 2
        weight 50
        fall 1
        rise 1
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eno16777984
    virtual_router_id 42
    priority 90

    track_script {
        odr_check
    }

    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.110.84
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you share what do you use in your healthcheck script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a using much simple configuration for the same purpose. Utility pidof must be on most OSs Linux by default. Try this for example:

```
vrrp_script check_haproxy
{
    script "pidof haproxy"
    interval 2
    weight 2
}
```

It's a working solution buddy.

Comment: is any way to use address of some script in script section instead of a command?